# What is a script to find lines in a text starting with a particular string and prepend # to those lines?

Tags: shell, applescript, prepend

I am looking for an AppleScript or shell script (or another script) that automates the prepending of # before each line that starts with a date formatted like this one: 2013-09-26 (or any other date)

I keep a log, but want to make headers using Markdown. Doing that manually for each of the notes I have is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/#&/' inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ cat in
foo
2012-01-20
bar
$ sed -r 's/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/#&/' in
foo
#2012-01-20
bar
```

EDIT: As pointed out by [user495470](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495470/user495470), on MacOS you'd need to use `-E` instead of `-r` in order to [enable extended regular expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html).

Comment: OS X's sed uses `-E` instead of `-r` for extended regex, and `-r` is not an alias for `-E` like in some other BSD seds.

Comment: @user495470 Thanks.  Don't use OS X much really; added the information.

Comment: Yeah! It worked! Thanks a lot! This saves a lot of time. And it is fun to get a good answer as well. Thanks again!